# iOS FBSDKShare API shareWithContent fails to post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook iOS Sharing SDK 4.1 but not getting a post off. I have an active session, but the following code does not post to my feed, and I do not get any of the callbacks either (success, error, or cancel), even though the caller is a FBSDKSharingDelegate. I have attempted to emulate the sample code in the SDK documentation but to no avail.

```
if ( [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"] ) {
    FBSDKShareLinkContent* content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = _Object.myPostServerURL;
    content.contentDescription = _Object.myPostDescription;
    content.contentTitle = @"New Post";
    content.imageURL = _Object.coverArtServerURL;
    BOOL ok = [[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self] share];
}
```

I've tried with and without the "share" message wrapped around the shareWithContent; I can't tell from the documentation if it is required. Either way, no callbacks to delegate, no post.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
   FBSDKShareLinkContent *tempContent=[[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    tempContent.contentTitle=@"hello";
    tempContent.contentDescription=@"desc";
    tempContent.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://camo.githubusercontent.com/67212912f8d2d6a474d1af756603f7c13c837112/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f375976386d53412e676966"];
    tempContent.contentURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://scrumptious-facebook.parseapp.com/meals/italian/?fb_action_ids=10200411040395078&fb_action_types=fb_sample_scrumps%3Aeat"];

    _shareAPI.delegate = self;
    _shareAPI.shareContent = tempContent;
    [_shareAPI share];
```

Also to use FBSDKShareAPI,You have to implement your for login and request for necessary permissions through u get FBSDKAccessToken,then only u can directly post to user feed.This is according to documentation of Facebook,If u want to show your own interface of sharing.

Currently may be your delgate may not work but might be ur app may face the issues of no access tokens and no  permission issues

```
[[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init]
     logInWithPublishPermissions:@[publish_actions]
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:publish_actions]) {

             [_shareAPI share];
         } else {
             // This would be a nice place to tell the user why publishing
             // is valuable.

         }
     }];


//Delegate methods

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{

}
 - (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer{

}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"%@",error);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion muku, but unfortunately there is no change.  I have confirmed that I have both an active token, and also publish_actions permission at the point where I try the share (see above).  What else could be wrong?

Comment: Its working for me .You also have to add your domain viz is contentURL to facebook dashboard.Also you have add Facebook Login  SDK to your  website (your domain).I have tested the above code.Just look for contentURL, that is issue  in ur case,thats y it is not allowing to share

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some configuration in your appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];}
```

and

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.}
```